# Mail List Management API?

Tags: api, email, spam, mailing-list

I'm building a website that needs to provide users with the ability to subscribe to new items in each category. So, potentially I'll have dozens of different mail lists, each with hundreds of subscribers.

On a previous site, I built the mechanism myself and it worked well enough. I did fall foul of various spam filters and blacklists though as I was just using the newsletter feature of Merak's mail server which isn't really what it's designed for.

I've been looking for a tool to manage it that might behave better in relation to spam filters etc. MailChimp looked like just the ticket as it's got a nice API that allows list management and they pay great heed to doing things right with respect to spam.

However, it doesn't quite offer my the flexibility I need - particularly with customising the look and feel of standard response forms etc. Whilst there are good tools for customising the look of the opt in/out emails, they have to be done on a list by list basis and that's not really going to work for me.

So, has anyone had a similar issue? Should I be looking for an alternative to MailChimp or going back to a simpler in-house build with something more appropriate to do the final mailshots (thousands of emails a day).